# Inheritance and isinstance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I just noticed that

```
isinstance(myob, MyClass)
```

does not only return `True` when `myob` is an instance of `MyClass` but also if `myob` is an instance of a class that inherits from `MyClass`.

To be more clear, consider the following:

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, cover)
        self._cover = cover

class Novel(Book):
    def __init__(self, cover, category):
        Book.__init__(self, cover)
        self._category = category
```

When instanciating Novel as follows:

```
novel = Novel('hardcover', 'police')
```

then

```
print(isinstance(novel, Book))
```

and

```
print (isinstance(novel , Novel))
```

both print `True`.

Why is that so? In my sense, `novel` is a `Novel` instance, not a `Book` one...

Also, relevant to this :

In order to get the "grand-mother" (sic) class, I do:

```
print(novel.__class__.__bases__)
```

Is there a more direct way?

Comment: A novel is a specialization of a book, but it still is a book.

Comment: Because Novels *are* Books. That's the relationship that inheritance describes.

Comment: This is where `type(novel) is Book` comes into play.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between type() and isinstance()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance)

Comment: This is OOP-standard. Isn't a novel still a book? Isn't a penguin still both a bird and an animal?

Comment: Guess you could say that `isinstance`-ness is inherited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This transitive behavior is how it should work intuitively ...

```
>>> class Text:
...:    pass
...:
...:
>>> class Book(Text):
...:    pass
...:
...:
>>> class Novel(Book):
...:    pass
...:
...:
>>> n = Novel()
>>> isinstance(n, Novel)
>>> True
>>> isinstance(n, Book)
>>> True
>>> isinstance(n, Text)
>>> True
```

... because a `Novel` [**is-a**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `Novel`, but also **is-a** `Book` and **is-a** `Text`.

If you want to know whether a class (or instance of a class) is a direct ancestor of another class, you can use the `__subclasses__` method of class objects.

```
>>> Text.__subclasses__()
>>> [__main__.Book]
>>> Book.__subclasses__()
>>> [__main__.Novel]
>>> Novel.__subclasses__()
>>> []
>>> 
>>> Novel in Text.__subclasses__()
>>> False
>>> type(n) in Text.__subclasses__()
>>> False
>>> Novel in Book.__subclasses__()
>>> True
>>> type(n) in Book.__subclasses__()
>>> True
```

edit: `YourClass.__bases__` also gives you all direct parent classes.

```
>>> Novel.__bases__
>>> (__main__.Book,)
```

Answer (score 4):

Inheritance is "is a" relationship - if `Duck` inherit from `Bird` then obviously a duck (instance of `Duck`) is ALSO a `bird` (instance of `Bird`), so the behaviour you observe is really the expected one (and this holds for all class-based OOPLs).

If you want to check the *exact* type of an object, you can get it using `type(obj)` - which will return the class of object - and do an identity test against the desired class, ie:

```
obj = 42
print(type(obj) is int)
```